# Don't understand the cause of this numpy ValueError

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

test=pd.read_csv('test.csv')
train=pd.read_csv('train.csv')

y=train['Survived'].reset_index(drop=True)

train_features = train.drop(['Survived'], axis=1)
test_features = test
features = pd.concat([train_features, test_features]).reset_index(drop=True)

features= features.drop(['Name'],axis=1)
features= features.drop(['Ticket'],axis=1)
features= features.drop(['Cabin'],axis=1)
features.isna().sum()

from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imp = Imputer()
features.iloc[:, [3,6]] = imp.fit_transform(features.iloc[:,[3,6]].values)

features['Embarked'] = features['Embarked'].fillna('S')

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
['Sex']=le.fit_transform(features['Sex'])
features['Embarked']=le.fit_transform(features['Embarked'])

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
one = OneHotEncoder()
features = one.fit_transform(features)
features = pd.DataFrame(list(features))

train = features.iloc[:len(y),:]
test=features.iloc[len(y):,:]

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lin_reg = LogisticRegression()
lin_reg.fit(train,y)
```

I'm getting the error below:

```
File "<ipython-input-1-e57e780501e5>", line 56, in <module>
    lin_reg.fit(train,y)

File
"C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py",
line 1220, in fit
    order="C")

File
"C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py",
line 573, in check_X_y
    ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)

File
"C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py",
line 433, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the message with:

```
In [53]: np.array(np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4]]))                                                   
Out[53]: array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([3, 4])], dtype=object)
In [54]: np.array(np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4]]),int)                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-8edc6222b80d> in <module>
----> 1 np.array(np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4]]),int)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

The inner array contains lists of different size, resulting in an object dtype array.  If I try to make a new array with a `int` dtype, I get the error.

You need to look more carefully at `train` and `y`.  What's their `shapes` and `dtype`.  If either is `object` dtype, or the shape is unexpected (e.g. 1d instead of 2d), you need to review how they are generated.

Comment: y is Series and train is a dataFrame

Comment: You have to dig a little deeper than that!